# Cannot access installation page of directus

Tags: directus

After Installation i navigate to /admin to access the installation page. But it redirects me to a login page (/admin/#/login). Because I didnt installed anything i cant log in to directus.

I tried to delete the config.php, because the support told me that should be the problem. The problem is I don't have any config.php file.

Comment: Could you provide more info on the current stack you're using? What server / how did you install?

Comment: @Rijk I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Apacha2, need anything else?

Comment: I you go directly to the API, does it work? Navigate to `/` instead of `/admin`. It should show something along the lines of "This api hasn't been configured yet". If that doesn't show up, the api itself isn't running properly.

Comment: @Rijk i got this output when I try to acces `/` : `{"error":{"code":3,"message":"Unauthorized request"}}`

Comment: I have the same problem after cloning from the repo. The server runs Apache 2, PHP 7.1.30, Mariadb. I tried installing under localhost or as a local domain with exactly the same results. Lozit answer moved things a bit further, but the installation does not start and does seem complete.
I tried to debug and even found attempts to log under config/logs/api.log.

Comment: i solved it. First I tried to reinstall my vps but that changed anything. Then I thought the problem comes from the database and I installed phpMyAdmin. During the installation there was a command that changed the encoding or something like that. After that command it worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

The config file is : /config/api.php

If you have one, delete it and try again.

If it doesn't work, you can create a config file manually :

```
bin/directus install:config -n <database-name> -u <mysql-user> -p <mysql-password>
bin/directus install:database
```

Then create an user :

```
bin/directus install:install -e <admin-email> -p <admin-password> -t <project-title>
```

Comment: Can you check if the database was created ? Do you have any data inside tables ? Do you have the data of your user ? Do you have an error message when you try to log-in ?